# Image of NSView with background

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsview

I'm trying to get an image of a view, so I can put it in a `NSImageView`.

I'm using `NSView`s `bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplayInRect:` method.
However, this method does only return the contents of the view, without background of the window.

How can I get the image of the whole view, as it looks on the screen, with background-color etc.?

---

### Current Code

```
- (NSImage *)imageOfView:(NSView *)view {
    NSBitmapImageRep* rep = [view bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplayInRect:view.bounds];
    [view cacheDisplayInRect:view.frame toBitmapImageRep:rep];

    return [[NSImage alloc] initWithCGImage:[rep CGImage] size:view.bounds.size];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement from the [project](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/ScreenSnapshot/Introduction/Intro.html)

```
/* Get the index for the chosen display from the CGDirectDisplayID array. */
NSInteger displaysIndex = [menuItem tag];
/* Make a snapshot image of the current display. */
CGImageRef image = CGDisplayCreateImage(displays[displaysIndex]);
```